# How to increase the number of connections in maven

Tags: java, maven

How can I increase the number of http(s) connections a maven build will use to download and upload Artifacts from the repository (Artifactory or similar).

I have seen this page: 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html

But it does not say what is the parameter and syntax to set it.

I am using Apache Maven 3.6.0

Comment: Can you explain the background of this question? What is your aim?

Comment: Test if increasing the number of connections makes ci builds faster.

Comment: Why won't you increase number of threads using -T? e.g. `mvn clean install -T100`

Comment: Most of the dependencies are already in the local repository, so I would not expect too much.

Comment: This is a different thing. I am aware of it and using it. But when you get to a phase where you need to upload 1000 files they will be limited by the default size of the pull which is 20.

Comment: @JFMeier if I am uploading 1000 files it will theoretically help.

Comment: Why are you uploading 1000 files? A maven site?

Comment: First question is: How many files are we talking about? Second: About what time are we talking about? Have you measured the time to upload all files? You mean the upload of the resulting artifacts is really the issue? How large are those files? Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade your Maven version to 3.6.1 cause there had been an fix for WAGON (for uploading/downloading files) ...Please try this first...It would be better to upgrade to most recent version of Maven...

Answer (score 4):

according to Maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) By default, Maven 2.1.0+ will download up to 5 artifacts (from different groups) at once. To change the size of the thread pool, start Maven using following switch option to change default value:

```
-Dmaven.artifact.threads
```

for example :

```
mvn -Dmaven.artifact.threads=1 verify
```

You may wish to set this option permanently, in which case you can use the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable. For example:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.artifact.threads=3
```

Comment: why can't I find the default value of this property! :(

Answer (score 2):

There is options for maven:
`maven.artifact.threads` for configuring parallel artifacst resolution

You can use it as is described on site:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

You can also add this properties to your settings.xml so will be affected for all builds:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>props</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <maven.artifact.threads>10</maven.artifact.threads>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I think it is only for download. I am looking for upload concurrently.